# How to find the nth binary permutation?

Tags: permutation

This is the last missing piece I need to complete my compression algorithm, new one. Let's say I have 4 bits with 2 bits set as 1, 0011. The total number of permutations for this number is 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100, 6 cases. This can be computed using the calculation.

4! / ((2!)(4-2)!) = 6

Now I want to be able to find the nth sequence, for instance 1st number is 0011, second number is 0101. So if I say n=5, I want to be able to get the 5th permutation sequence 1010 from the initial 0011. How do I do this?

Comment: You can iterate them, this solution works up to 63 bit numbers: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/162983/21279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two 1 in the binary, it's not too difficult.

When the highest 1 bit locate at `x` position, the number of permutation is `x`.

So that, the highest bit position is the smallest `a` (starts from 0), subjecting to `a*(a+1)/2 >= n`. You can easily find `a` by a O(n) loop.

Then the least bit position is `a*(a+1)/2-n` (starts from 0)

For example, when `n` is 5, the smallest `a` is 3, and the least bit position is 1, so that the answer is `1010`

Comment: Hi, how about for larger numbers such as 00111 and n=8?

Comment: I mean to find the middle bit